# In need of some guidance to make this Arduino sensor circuit

Tags: arduino, sensor

These two circuits are given as instructions for the moisture/humidity sensor.

Am I suppose to make the one on the left AND the one on the right?

The right one seems doable, but the left confuses me:

What does P1, P2 mean? What does S mean? How do these circuits relate to each other? I don't get why there's two circuits. Is it the same ground? Same Vcc? Do these two circuits go on the same bread board?

[image]

Comment: Please include a link to the manufacturer datasheet of the moisture/humidity sensor in question.

Answer (score 2):

This schematic is the *internal* schematic of a [module](https://www.osepp.com/electronic-modules/breakout-boards/94-humidity-moisture-breakout):

[image]

If you are *using* the module you need only connect it to GND/Vcc and two pins of the Arduino (one digital, one analog). The 4 pins shown on the header (at the 'top' of the PCB) provide those connections. You'll need to find an appropriate library to communicate with the DHT11 if you don't feel like finding the detailed datasheet information and writing it.

**Inside** the module, there are two separate circuits, independent save for the power and ground. If you are attempting to *copy* the internal circuit of their module, you can make one or the other, or both.

It is connected to two individual inputs on the Arduino, plus power and ground.

The SS9013 is used as a crude moisture measurement circuit. A resistance between the two probe points of around 20kΩ will give you about 2V out (*very* roughly).

And the schematic has nothing, nada, to do with a "reed switch module", very sloppy editing on the part of the seller.

By the way, it passes DC current through the probe so the probe will likely corrode away relatively quickly from electrolytic action. And the circuit is beta-dependent on the individual SS9013 and temperature, so it's very much crude.

The DHT11 is a (possibly legacy) low-cost temperature and humidity sensor module made by Chinese manufacturer Guangzhou Aosong Electronics with a single wire digital interface. All the smarts in this 'product' are inside that module.

---

All the points marked Vcc are connected together.

All the points marked with the ground symbol are connected together.

You can assemble this on a breadboard, a PCB, perf board, or whatever you like. The wires between the module and the Arduino should not be too long.

Answer (score 1):

> Am I suppose to make the one on the left AND the one on the right?

Not sure, depends on where you got the schematic and what your intentions are.

> What does P1, P2 mean?

They are connectors to nets somewhere else in the schematic or PCB connectors, look at the PCB and see where they go.

> What does S mean?

S is an output of an open collector. If something shorted P1 to P2, then the voltage on S would go to VCC-0.7V. If P1 and P2 were open, then S would go near 0V.

> I don't get why there's two circuits. Is it the same ground? Same Vcc?

Yes, same ground, yes same VCC.

> Do these two circuits go on the same bread board?

Probably

Comment: Thanks. Is it possible that P1, P2 refer to the two prongs on my moisture sensor, and the circuit on the left is simply the circuit within my sensor? (there appears to be a little circuit housed in there).I got the schematic from the manufacturer website. Thus I only need to produce the circuit on the right to make it function?  I don't know much about electronics as you can tell

Comment: https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/01/08/how-to-say-thanks-in-an-answer/